# How do we allocate a pointer to an array

Tags: c

I have been asked in an interview, there is an pointer to an array of 10 integers, something like this below.

```
 int (*p)[10];
```

How do you allocate it dynamically ??

This is something I have done

```
p=(int *)malloc(10*sizeof(int));
```

But it looks wrong because I am not doing the right typecast.

So I would like to know what's the type of *p ??

Like int *p ,p is of type int.

Answer (score 9):

Here is how to allocate:

```
p = malloc(sizeof *p);
```

or

```
p = malloc(sizeof (int [10]));
```

`p` is of type `int (*)[10]` and `*p` is of type `int [10]`.

`p` is pointer to an array 10 of `int` and `*p` is an array 10 of `int`.

Comment: p=(int (*)[10])malloc(10*sizeof(int); Is this gonna to be ok?

Comment: `sizeof (int (*)[10])` is the size of the pointer, not the size of the pointee, so that'll allocate too little.

Comment: @DanielFischer oh thank you, fixed in the answer. I fix it also in the comment.

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar in C you should not cast `malloc` return value. See c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html for the rationale. Otherwise `malloc(10 * sizeof(int))` is not wrong but `malloc(sizeof (int [10]))` is more correct in this particular case.